# Show newly added record as dirty i.e. red color on top

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am adding new record in grid like below

```
    var newRow = Ext.create(gridModel);
    rowEditPlugin.cancelEdit();
    gridStore.insert(0, newRow);
    reportGrid.getView().refresh();
    reportGrid.getView().getSelectionModel().select(0);
    //rowEditPlugin.startEdit(0);
    rowEditPlugin.startEditByPosition({
        row: newRow,
        column: 0
    });
```

I want this newly added record to be shown as dirty, user should know that this row is added newly i.e. red marks on top of each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a method to the `viewConfig` of your grid, called `getRowClass`. This method will allow you to [customise the CSS class for the row](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0-classic/Ext.view.Table.html#method-getRowClass).

You can tell if your record is newly inserted or not using the [`Model#phantom` property](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0-classic/Ext.data.Model.html#property-phantom)

And, finally, you can modify the CSS for your application using SASS/Fashion to change the appearance of your newly added rows.